# Joomla 4 : Categories::getInstance('productshop.products'); not working for my custom extension

Tags: extensions, joomla-4.x, categories

| extension | title | alias |
| --- | --- | --- |
| com_content | Uncategorised | uncategorised |
| com_banners | Sample Data-Banners | sample-data-banners |
| com_banners | Sample Data-Newsfeeds | sample-data-newsfeeds |
| com_newsfeeds | Sample Data-Contact | sample-data-contact |
| com_contact | Joomla! | joomla |
| com_productdeal.products | products Category one | products-category |

If I try to print categories for Content, Banners, or Contact then getInstance function returns data correctly.

```
$categories = Categories::getInstance('Content');
```

When trying to print the categories of another custom extension, it returns nothing.

```
$categories = Categories::getInstance('productdeal.products');
```

Why can't I use custom extensions with `Categories::getInstance()`?

Answer (score 1):

To use categories in your component, you need to register the 'CategoryFactory' in the 'provider' file

Example from administrator/component/com_content/services/provider.php

```
public function register(Container $container)
    {
        $container->set(AssociationExtensionInterface::class, new AssociationsHelper());
        $container->registerServiceProvider(new CategoryFactory('\\Joomla\\Component\\Content'));
        $container->registerServiceProvider(new MVCFactory('\\Joomla\\Component\\Content'));
        $container->registerServiceProvider(new ComponentDispatcherFactory('\\Joomla\\Component\\Content'));
        $container->registerServiceProvider(new RouterFactory('\\Joomla\\Component\\Content'));

        $container->set(
            ComponentInterface::class,
            function (Container $container) {
                $component = new ContentComponent($container->get(ComponentDispatcherFactoryInterface::class));

                $component->setRegistry($container->get(Registry::class));
                $component->setMVCFactory($container->get(MVCFactoryInterface::class));
                $component->setCategoryFactory($container->get(CategoryFactoryInterface::class));
                $component->setAssociationExtension($container->get(AssociationExtensionInterface::class));
                $component->setRouterFactory($container->get(RouterFactoryInterface::class));

                return $component;
            }
        );
    }
```

Also take a look at the file: administrator/component/com_content/src/Extension/ContentComponent.php